# LINQ Type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two objects that I want to join `_locations` and `lrsLocations`. I want to update `_locations` attributes with the corresponding `lrsLocations`. To do this I am using LINQ to get references to both options and then going through and updating `ms2` attributes to be `lrs` (I know this isn't what LINQ was made for so I am open to new ideas. I am using this LINQ query now:

```
        var joinResult =
            from
                ms2 in _locations
            from
                lrs in lrsLocations
            where
                ms2.LRS_ID == lrs.attributes.route_id
                &&
                ms2.LRS_LOC_PT == lrs.attributes.measure
            select
                new {ms2, lrs};
```

It works but I really need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so after some googling I attempting:

```
var joinResult  = from ms2 in _locations
                    join lrs in lrsLocations on new { ms2.LRS_ID, ms2.LRS_LOC_PT } 
                    equals new { lrs.attributes.route_id, lrs.attributes.measure } into merge
                    from lrs in merge.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { ms2, lrs };
```

The issue is that the `join lrs` complains: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXwgR.png (Click for picture)

So I either need a way to convert my working LINQ to be a LEFT OUTER JOIN, or understand what the problem is talking about in the new one, because a google didn't give me much insight.

Comment: check to make sure that `LRS_ID` is the same type as `route_id`, same with `LRS_LOC_PT` and `measure`. If it doesn't, cast them to the correct type.

Comment: LRS_ID and route_id are both `string`, and LRS_LOC_PT and measure are both `double?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous types in your JOIN must have the same property names:

```
join lrs in lrsLocations on new { ms2.LRS_ID, ms2.LRS_LOC_PT } 
                     equals new { LRS_ID = lrs.attributes.route_id, LRS_LOC_PT = lrs.attributes.measure }
```

Obviously the *types* have to match as well.  If they don't you need a conversion or a cast.

Comment: This was it. Thanks a lot